# MYSQL update trigger not updating the columns

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this trigger

```
DELIMITER ;

 DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER when_auction_ends
    AFTER UPDATE ON Auctions
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

    SELECT A.vin, A.status, A.winner, A.minprice, B.amount, B.buyer INTO @vin, @stat, @winner, @minprice, @amount, @buyer

    FROM Auctions A, Bids B WHERE A.status = 'Inactive' AND A.winner = null AND A.vin = B.vin AND B.amount = (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM Bids B WHERE B.vin = A.vin AS 




    IF @amount < @minprice THEN

    UPDATE Auctions
    SET A.winner = 'NONE'
    WHERE A.vin = B.vin;

    ELSEIF @amount >= @minprice THEN

    UPDATE Auctions
    SET A.winner = B.buyer
    WHERE A.vin = B.vin;



    END IF ;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But when it activates, the values are not updated. I am thinking that its because mysql does not know what A.winner is in "SET A.winner". I tried looking online on how to use OLD and NEW but did not have any luck.

Comment: Do you get an error or does it silently fail?

Comment: @lucksch it silently fails, no error. The column just doesnt update

Comment: `A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.`, see [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Restrictions for Stored Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Comment: I don't think this trigger exists at all. It contains several errors that would prevent you from creating the trigger.
For example, you use table aliases `A` and `B` in your SELECT statement, but the subsequent UPDATE is a separate statement. Table aliases do not carry over to later statements.

Comment: Is there any workaround to this?